Ошибка создания топика (Kafka)
При выполнении Get запроса с пагинацией возникает ошибка создания топика в микросервисном приложении.
Код запроса:
@GetMapping
@Operation(summary = "Get all habits", description = "Retrieves a list of all habits.")
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "List of habits retrieved successfully",
        content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = HabitDto.class, type = "array")))
public ResponseEntity<List<HabitDto>> getAllHabits(
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") int page,
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "10")int size,
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "id") String sort
) {
    String[] sortParams = sort.split(",");
    Sort sortOrder;
    if (sortParams.length > 1 && "desc".equalsIgnoreCase(sortParams[1])) {
        sortOrder = Sort.by(sortParams[0]).descending(); // Сортировка по убыванию
    } else {
        sortOrder = Sort.by(sortParams[0]).ascending(); // Сортировка по возрастанию
    }
    PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, size, sortOrder);
    Page<Habit> habitsPage = habitServiceImpl.getAllHabits(pageRequest);
    List<HabitDto> dtos = habitsPage.getContent().stream()
            .map(HabitMapper::toDto)
            .toList();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(dtos);
}

Тут метод getAllHabits выдаёт список всех "привычек" у пользователя. И они возвращаются с пагинацией.
В ходе запуска микросервиса выпадает такая ошибка:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 2 larger than available brokers: 1.

Как это можно исправить?
Так выглядит ошибка:


А кто выбрасывает эксепшен?

2024-10-11T23:35:13.631+03:00 ERROR 6392 --- [habit-service] [           main] o.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin  : Failed to create topics
Спринг выбрасывает

Если не будешь отвечать на вопросы мы не сможем помочь. Еше раз, какой метод выбрасывает эксепшен?

Дело в том, что не пишется какой метод. Щас добавлю скрин в вопрос

at habittracker.habitservice.HabitServiceApplication.main(HabitServiceApplication.java:11) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 2 larger than available brokers: 1.

Нужнл найти где кафка сконфигурена и исправить количество требуемых реплик. Ну или добавить инстансов в кафка кластер.

тут есть пара полезных мыслей.

А что если у меня нет файла server.properties? В конфигурации Kafka, как мне правильно создать и подключить эту конфигурацию к кайфке?

Спасибо! Изменил фактор репликации и все создалось)

Вопервых можно поискать бин с типом NewTopic, а во вторых где указан хост к которому кафка конектица?

Оставь ответ для потомков.
